# Add custom control to DevExpress GridControl

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a custom DateTimePicker control that prepared for Persian calendar. Is there any way to add it to the DevExpress GridControl column?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**From:** [Creating a custom (RepositoryItem) ImageComboBox](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q424102/creating-a-custom-repositoryitem-imagecombobox)

> If you wish to use your custom control in GridControl, it is necessary
>   to create an editor and its ***RepositoryItem*** descendants.
>
> Please refer to the [Custom Editors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4716) and [How to register a custom
>   editor for use in the XtraGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A1237.aspx) articles for complete information
>   on how to create custom controls. You can find some custom editor
>   descendants in our examples: [editor descendants](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=descendant&p=T4%7CP1%7C4&d=16).
>
> The ***RepositoryItem*** class contains editor settings and is used as
>   a template for cells in the grid. In the display mode, GridControl
>   only draws cells content via RepositoryItem's methods. In the edit
>   mode, GridControl creates a corresponding editor via the
>   RepositoryItem.CreateEditor method. Thus, if you wish to add items to
>   the editor used in the grid on its initialization, implement this at
>   the RepositoryItem level.

You can set an editor for the auto filter row if you handle [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event with following code

```
    RepositoryItemDateEdit rd = new RepositoryItemDateEdit();
    void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
      GridView view = sender as GridView;
      if(e.Column.FieldName == "DOB" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle)) {
          e.RepositoryItem = rd;
      }
    }
```

Review the [Assigning Editors to Columns and Card Fields](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument746) help article to learn how to assign a specific editor to a particular GridView's column.

I hope you will find this information useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I contact you by email?

Comment: @R.Salehi: You can put your questions here or [DevExpress forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create). Provide code in question where you are facing problem so that everyone can understand the issue and reply you for correct solution. If it does work then you can find helping hands [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Home/Community/MVP.xml).

Comment: Additionally, the [RepositoryItemAnyControl class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCustomEditorRepositoryItemAnyControltopic) can be used to place any custom editor in a GridControl, TreeList etc...